# Summing a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

I am running Python 3.6 and Pandas 0.19.2 in PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2 and am trying to ensure a set of rows in my dataframe adds up to 1.

Initially my dataframe looks as follows:

```
 hello     world     label0    label1    label2
 abc       def       1.0       0.0       0.0
 why       not       0.33      0.34      0.33
 hello     you       0.33      0.38      0.15
```

I proceed as follows:

```
# get list of label columns (all column headers that contain the string 'label')
label_list = df.filter(like='label').columns

# ensure every row adds to 1
if (df[label_list].sum(axis=1) != 1).any():
    print('ERROR')
```

Unfortunately this code does not work for me. What seems to be happening is that instead of summing my rows, I just get the value of the first column in my filtered data. In other words: `df[label_list].sum(axis=1)`returns:

```
0     1.0
1     0.33
2     0.33
```

This should be trivial, but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks up front for the help!

UPDATE:

This is an excerpt from my original data after I have filtered for label columns:

```
    label0 label1 label2 label3 label4 label5 label6 label7 label8
1    0.34    0.1    0.1    0.1    0.2    0.4    0.1    0.1    1.2
2    0.34    0.1    0.1    0.1    0.2    0.4    0.1    0.1    1.2
3    0.34    0.1    0.1    0.1    0.2    0.4    0.1    0.1    1.2
4    0.34    0.1    0.1    0.1    0.2    0.4    0.1    0.1    1.2
5    0.34    0.1    0.1    0.1    0.2    0.4    0.1    0.1    1.2
6    0.34    0.1    0.1    0.1    0.2    0.4    0.1    0.1    1.2
7    0.34    0.1    0.1    0.1    0.2    0.4    0.1    0.1    1.2
8    0.34    0.1    0.1    0.1    0.2    0.4    0.1    0.1    1.2
9    0.34    0.1    0.1    0.1    0.2    0.4    0.1    0.1    1.2
```

My code from above still does not work, and I still have absolutely no idea why. When I run my code in python console everything works perfectly fine, but when I run my code in Pycharm 2016.3.2, `label_data.sum(axis=1)` just returns the values of the first column.

Comment: What return `label_list = df.filter(like='label').columns` ?

Comment: It seems there is something wrong with column names, check it by `print (df.columns.tolist())`

Comment: For your sample it return `['hello', 'world', 'label0', 'label1', 'label2']`

Comment: `label_list` evalutes to `['label0', 'label1', 'label2']`. My code works perfectly fine in Python console on the dummy data set described above. My original dataset still breaks though. Changing the names of my 'label' variables yields varying weird behaviors.

Comment: Is possible reasign new column names by `df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3']`?

Comment: I tried that but the results are the same

Comment: Thanks for the catch: `axis=1`. In fact both dont work though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my data type was not consistent. I used `astype(float)` and things worked out.

Answer (score 0):

With your sample data for me it works. Just try to reproduce your sample adding a new column `check` to control the sum:

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   hello world  label0  label1  label2
0    abc   def    1.00    0.00    0.00
1    why   not    0.33    0.34    0.33
2  hello   you    0.33    0.38    0.15

In [4]: df['check'] = df.sum(axis=1)

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   hello world  label0  label1  label2  check
0    abc   def    1.00    0.00    0.00   1.00
1    why   not    0.33    0.34    0.33   1.00
2  hello   you    0.33    0.38    0.15   0.86

In [6]: label_list = df.filter(like='label').columns

In [7]: label_list
Out[7]: Index([u'label0', u'label1', u'label2'], dtype='object')

In [8]: df[label_list].sum(axis=1)
Out[8]: 
0    1.00
1    1.00
2    0.86
dtype: float64

In [9]: if (df[label_list].sum(axis=1) != 1).any():
   ...:     print('ERROR')
   ...:     
ERROR
```

Comment: You are right. Code runs perfectly fine in python console.